# SwiftUI: How to make infinite vibrations

Tags: ios, swift, vibration

I am making a vibration app. On tapping on the button specific vibrating pattern is being played. But I am struggling with making it infinitive.

Here is my vibration function

```
func complexSuccess() {
        guard CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware().supportsHaptics else { return }
        var events = [CHHapticEvent]()
        

        for i in stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: speed){
            
            let intensity = CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: strength)
            let sharpness = CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticSharpness, value: sharpness)
            let event = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticTransient, parameters: [intensity, sharpness], relativeTime: TimeInterval(i))
            
            events.append(event)
        }
        do {
            let pattern = try CHHapticPattern(events: events, parameters: [])
            let player = try engine?.makePlayer(with: pattern)
            try player?.start(atTime: 0)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to play pattern: \(error.localizedDescription).")
        }
    }
```

For now, it has 100 as a final number but I want it to go forever. Please help me.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to make it with stride or some kind of counting.

Comment: @KishanBhatiya App crashes.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have tried both ways and in both examples app crashes and give me 'Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue'

Comment: @green8 Can you Please let me know you just want only to Vibrate the phone infinite times or do you want to achieve this by playing a specific pattern only?  If any other way will be fine you to achieve this then let me know I have post my answer

Comment: I want to achieve a specific vibration pattern to be repeated infinitely.

Comment: @green8 - what type of "pattern" are you trying to create? From the code you've shown, it *appears* to just generate a simple "tap" every `speed` seconds?